# First and Last name tables to increase performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say that I have a customer table:

```
CustomerID | FirstName | LastName 
1          | John      | Smith     
2          | John      | Adams
3          | Kevin     | Smith
4          | Kevin     | Adams
```

Now imagine that this table has 200k+ rows. Would it increase performance to create a separate FirstName and LastName table as shown below and then using joins to get the view above?

Example:

```
FirstNameID | FirstName
1           | John
2           | Kevin
```

---

```
LastNameID | LastName
1          | Adam
2          | Smith
```

---

```
CustomerID | FirstNameID | LastNameID
1          | 1           | 2
2          | 1           | 1
3          | 2           | 2
4          | 2           | 1
```

Comment: So instead of querying one row in one table, query a row in the customer table, then make two additional queries and join the results? You guess which is faster.

Comment: This has *nothing* to do with normalization.

Comment: Took off the normalization tags.

Comment: You could always try it.  However, even if it was, I don't think it's worth the time and effort.

Comment: My thought behind it was that if the table was large enough would the space saved increase performance enough to justify the others?

Comment: This would make inserting data more long winded too.  Instead of inserting `John` and `Smith` in `FirstName` and `LastName` of the `Customer` table you would need a look up or join to get the ID.  Then if the name does not exist you have to carry out another insert.  I wouldn't if I were you.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' Removing redundancies definitely has to do with normalization, what makes you say otherwise?

Comment: @GoatCO - That's why I originally added those tags but I wanted to avoid a "What constitutes normalization" debate.

Comment: It absolutely is normalization - the question is whether it is sensible. And that really depends. On the queries. I remember once upon a time we did the same thing - for whole addresses (city, country, street names on top of the names you have) and it boosted performance and took database size down seriously. Today - not so sure. Servers CAN be larger. A lot depends on the queries. I would give it a try from the query side - doing the change on a copy of the database will not take a lot of time.

Comment: @GoatCO: This doesn't remove any redundancy. It just replaces repeated (not redundant) strings with repeated integers.

Comment: You speak about 200k records as if that's a great number; it really isn't.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' I see your point, you'd contend that it has to be a combination of fields, ie moving first and last as a pair to a names table and using a single name ID rather than two separate name Id's that would remove redundancy.  I've always thought of replacing a longer string with a shorter ID type to be a form of redundancy removal, as it's reducing the size of the repeated values.

Comment: @GoatCO: No. Normalization never introduces a new column. In your example, name ID is a new column. Also, normalization through BCNF is concerned with the *functional dependencies* between attributes, not with the *size* of *values*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your query workload. This is a simple form of data compression. Reducing the set of data that is needed to answer a given query can improve performance.

On the other hand you introduce overhead in many places. It is a trade-off. If you want to retrieve the values of those columns you now need to join. DML becomes slower as well.

Since the name columns are probably rather small it is hard to imagine a query workload that would benefit from this scheme.

`DATA_COMPRESSION` and backup compression can be alternatives. They make very different trade-offs.

Just to prove that there is merit to your scheme: Imagine very long names and a huge (TB-sized) table. The space savings would be significant because there are rather few distinct names.

Comment: No, compression will not work because likely the clustered key is on CustomerId - which means that you get effectively random names. WIll make a difference but not one that high. Compression mostly is great when you manage to have the correct clustered index.

Comment: Depends on how many names fit on a page. Maybe many "Smith"'s. Good point.

Comment: Actually no. Problem is that unless you live in china (which mostly has 5 family names I have been told) you have a lot of them. People sadly will not be ordered by "Smith" but MOST likely be an ID (1,2,3).... which means the order of names is random. Not many Smiths on a page then.

Comment: That's what I meant. If the data is very skewed (yet randomly ordered) page compression still works.

Answer (score 4):

Whether such a move would increase performance depends on what queries you perform, but it is likely to do the opposite for many of the queries that I envision you wanting to perform.

Comment: I'm curious what queries could be faster?

Comment: Any that are written by a smart developer on a server that mostly visualizes. As long as you do not filter there is no need to even READ the name and surname tables in any query as you can get the names from a cache. Been there, done that, got more than 10 times speed increase - but our use case was VERY special.

Comment: I'm surprised this is the accepted answer since all it says is "maybe it works, maybe not".

Comment: @usr TomTom has provided some really good information on it throughout various comments. I think the concept is correct if implemented right but the practicality isn't really there.

Comment: @Force of course it is your choice, but why do you accept the answer that helps you the least? You haven't interacted with mine as far as I can tell, although it answers what you wanted to know.

Comment: I think you're right. The core concept of what I was doing was reducing the amount of data being stored. The information you provided would be more valuable to others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any action involving the names that would be made faster by having to join three tables.

Short answer: No.

Comment: Replacing text with ID numbers has nothing to do with normalization.

Comment: I've removed the reference to normalization. I'm pretty sure I was given an example like this when I learned about normalization. It had to do with removing all redundant data. I was taught that it was something "beyond" third normal form, and beyond practical - an academic exercise with no benefit. But that was a long time ago and I may not remember correctly.

Comment: It most certainly does have to do with normalization, but I agree that it's likely not worthwhile.

Comment: Not sure. First, you can get the names WITHOUT joins - there is no reason in some cases to not load the other tables into a dictionary in memory. Been there, done that - but OUR case was special (online phone directory of a country - so effectively changes came via batch processing, and all queries were reads).

Comment: @GoatCO: You're mistaken. There's no such thing as "replace text with id numbers" normal form.